# Mac Installer to Check for Mono,Auto Download and install if not installed

Tags: macos, shell, mono, package, installation

I have an app that depends on Mono Framwork.Im trying to create a shell script that will download and install Mono Framework on the users Mac with minimal interaction.I cannot find any resources related to this.The tool that i will be using is this http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

This tool has an option to insert pre and post install scripts so i need to check if Mono is installed otherwise need to download and install.

I can use this to check for Mono

```
#!/bin/sh

#get the bundle's MacOS directory full path
DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)

#change these values to match your app
EXE_PATH="$DIR\appname.exe"
PROCESS_NAME=appname
APPNAME="AppName"

#set up environment
MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$DIR:$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/lib:/lib:/usr/lib"
export PATH="$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/bin:$PATH"

#mono version check
REQUIRED_MAJOR=2
REQUIRED_MINOR=4

VERSION_TITLE="Cannot launch $APPNAME"
VERSION_MSG="$APPNAME requires the Mono Framework version $REQUIRED_MAJOR.$REQUIRED_MINOR or later."
DOWNLOAD_URL="http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html"

MONO_VERSION="$(mono --version | grep 'Mono JIT compiler version ' |  cut -f5 -d\ )"
MONO_VERSION_MAJOR="$(echo $MONO_VERSION | cut -f1 -d.)"
MONO_VERSION_MINOR="$(echo $MONO_VERSION | cut -f2 -d.)"
if [ -z "$MONO_VERSION" ] \
    || [ $MONO_VERSION_MAJOR -lt $REQUIRED_MAJOR ] \
    || [ $MONO_VERSION_MAJOR -eq $REQUIRED_MAJOR -a $MONO_VERSION_MINOR -lt $REQUIRED_MINOR ] 
then
    osascript \
    -e "set question to display dialog \"$VERSION_MSG\" with title \"$VERSION_TITLE\" buttons {\"Cancel\", \"Download...\"} default button 2" \
    -e "if button returned of question is equal to \"Download...\" then open location \"$DOWNLOAD_URL\""
    echo "$VERSION_TITLE"
    echo "$VERSION_MSG"
    exit 1
fi

#get an exec command that will work on the current OS version
OSX_VERSION=$(uname -r | cut -f1 -d.)
if [ $OSX_VERSION -lt 9 ]; then  # If OSX version is 10.4
    MONO_EXEC="exec mono"
else
    MONO_EXEC="exec -a \"$PROCESS_NAME\" mono"
fi

#create log file directory if it doesn't exist
LOG_FILE="$HOME/Library/Logs/$APPNAME/$APPNAME.log"
mkdir -p "`dirname \"$LOG_FILE\"`"

#run app using mono
$MONO_EXEC $MONO_OPTIONS "$EXE_PATH" $* 2>&1 1> "$LOG_FILE"
```

But how to download and install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Downloading/Install via CLI:

#### Lastest Mono version example:

```
MDK_PKG_ID="com.xamarin.mono-MDK.pkg"
MDK_PKG="mdk-latest.pkg"
MDK_URL="http://download.mono-project.com/archive/${MDK_PKG}"
curl -O ${MDK_URL}
sudo installer -pkg ${MDK_PKG} -target /
```

#### Specific Mono version example:

```
MDK_PKG_ID="com.xamarin.mono-MDK.pkg"
MDK_PKG = "MonoFramework-MDK-4.2.1.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg"
MDK_URL = "http://download.mono-project.com/archive/4.2.1//macos-10-x86/#{MDK_PKG}"
curl -O ${MDK_URL}
sudo installer -pkg ${MDK_PKG} -target /
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195371/mkbundled-mono-exe-checking-for-dependency-in-library-folder