# MKBundled Mono Exe checking for Dependency in Library Folder

Tags: macos, xamarin, mono, mkbundle

I have bundled an Exe with Mono in Mac using

```
export AS="as -arch i386"
export CC="cc -arch i386 -framework CoreFoundation -lobjc -liconv"
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/bin:$PATH
mkbundle -- static myapp.exe  MonoMac.dll --deps -o myapp
```

It successfully produces the native application myapp.
I copied the lib directory from mono folder and pasted it on desktop because the app uses **GTK** for User Interface.

I'm trying to launch the application using  the following ***script.sh***

```
VAR=`pwd`
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$VAR/lib:/usr/lib"
./myapp
```

The  ***app successfully launches provided that Mono is installed in Library folder*** if i remove Mono.Framework from the Library Folder i get the following error

[image]

***My question is isn't the static Flag used to include Mono Runtime with the Exe and produce a non dependent Native code(Except GTK for which i have set the DYLIB Path),Why is it looking for Mono in the Library Folder?***

Comment: @prosseek Can you please help me with this.

Comment: @sburnicki Can you please take a look.

Comment: @lex-li Please take a look.

Comment: @miguel-de-icaza Please take a look

Comment: @poupou Can you please help me with this.Im stuck here.

Comment: @knocte Please help me out.